# When I using vim in my putty program, I have an autocomplete issue

Tags: vim, putty

I'm using vim in putty program, I want to see my autocomplete list ,but only saw the gray background

In my host server(laptop), when using vim, I can see my autocomplete list

have you ever experienced this issue? if have,
Can you give me a your solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a terminal, Vim draws its entire user interface via the available characters and highlighting. It looks like you have very few colors and highlighting attributes available, so **the completion popup is drawn grey-on-grey**, so you don't see anything. You can verify this via

```
:highlight Pmenu
```

which would then also just print a grey bar.

To fix this, follow the usual playbook:

- How many colors are available: `:set t_Co?` tells you
- Is that expected? If not (PuTTY should support 256 colors), what's the `TERM` value (something like `xterm-256color` would be good).
- Does the colorscheme (`:colorscheme` tells you the name) support your environment? Check the entire `:hi` output whether it all looks fine, maybe try out a few different schemes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!!  I fixed this problem.

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.